# Datapower to SFDC integration - session management

Tags: web-services, oauth-2.0, salesforce, ibm-datapower

I am trying a scenario where Datapower invokes a web-service on SFDC. For Datapower to be able to invoke services, it needs to first get the authentication token from SFDC and use that token in each web-service request to be able to invoke the web-service.

Is there a simple way in datapower to do this? As the token generated by SFDC is valid for some time, can datapower manage this information internally or will we need to maintain it on a cache (XC10?) and deal with accessing the cache from the integration box ?

Your inputs would be really helpful..

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an XC10 device here, XC10 is needed when you want to cache a lot of name/value pairs. After you call the SFDC service from a Web Service Proxy (WSP) via url-open/soap-call you get the authentication token from SFDC and store it in a local/context variable and also store the current timestamp, and session timeout parameters in other local/context variables, and use them in further SFDC webservice calls. There are other ways of doing this and I hope you got the idea.